# Starter motor spins but engine does not crank

Tags: chevrolet, starter, truck

I have an intermittent starter problem on my 95 Chevy K1500 pickup truck.  When I turn the ignition, I hear the starter motor spinning but the engine does not turn over.  If I put the truck in gear and let it roll a short distance, then try again, the truck starts as normal.

It would seem that the starter motor is not engaging the flywheel for some reason.  Is the starter bad?

Thanks

Comment: The starter motor isn't bad, the starter solenoid is bad, more times than I can could, people replace a whole lot of unnecessary parts, when all those goes bad is one single component. No need to buy a whole new starter, just look for the starter solenoid. But before you do, take the solenoid off and test it, when power is applied, the plunger should pull inward, which says it's pushing the starter motor into the flywheel. When starter solenoids go out, it sounds like a drill going off, no noticeable spark but there's a spinning noise like it wants to give one

Comment: Most of the time a new starter is not much more than a solenoid. Replace the complete starter.

Comment: @Moab - Especially for a SBC starter ... dime a dozen ... well, maybe a *bit* more than that ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  For my vehicle, the price for a new solenoid was $26, or for a whole new motor it was $85 (AC Delco).  Since it’s not too expensive I ordered the motor.